# React Native - Expo - How to check if Dark mode is enabled?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I have read in the Expo/RN documentation, that for getting the system color (dark/light) we should use [this API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/appearance/) from react native.

So, I have decided to create my custom hook

```
import { Appearance } from "react-native";

export default function useIsDarkModeEnabled() {
  return Appearance.getColorScheme() === "dark";
}
```

But for some reason, it is always returning me false. I am testing on iOS 14, with dark theme enabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I check the current appearance of the device I use the useColorScheme() function, not getColorScheme().

You can use Context to persist it throughout the application, or put it at the root of your app and pass it down to your components as props (not the best). To persist the theme, you can use AsyncStorage to store the last state of the appearance.

Then whenever the application opens, it will pull that last state unless the device has changed its appearance since then.